# REALM Append list into linkingObjects

Tags: swift, object, append, realm

I want to use realm to append all data in one VC.

parentVC is showing Category List, in ParentVC can only append new Category

childVC is showing toDoItem List, and can only append to selectedCategory.toDoList

I created a new VC "addToDoListVC", to achieve result of "Adding new toDoItems to selected todoListCategory".

below is my code and image shown is the new addToDoListVC layout.

[addToDoItemVC layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWAPP.png)

```
class Category : Object {
    @objc dynamic var categoryName : String = "" 

    let ofToDoItem = List<ToDoItem>()
}

class ToDoList : Object {
    @objc dynamic var toDoItem : String = "" 

    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "ofToDoItem")
}
```

```
addItemVC

let realm = try! Realm()
    var categorySelection : Results<Category>?

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryNamePicker: UIPickerView!

    @IBAction func addItemBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let currentCategory = self.categorySelection {
          do {
     try! realm.write
      let newToDoItem = ToDoList()
         **// HOW DO I ADD THE ITEM TO SELECTED CATEGORY?**
         newToDoItem.toDoItem = textField.text

                    selectedCategory[**???**].ofToDoItem.append(newToDoItem)
**[// I can append data into selected category by "selectedCategory\[0\].ofToDoItem.append(newToDoItem)" but it is hardcoded.][1]**  
                }
            }

        }



//MARK:- PICKERVIEW METHODS
extension ParentVC : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return categorySelection?.count ?? 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return categorySelection?[row].categoryName
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        categoryName.text = categorySelection?[row].categoryName

    }
```

Comment: Please include images *in the question*. Links can break over time and if they do, future readers won't be able to see the image.

Comment: If you want to add an object to a list, append it to the list inside a write transaction (if the realm object is being managed). So assuming your selectedCategory is already stored in realm just `selectedCategory.ofToDoItem.append(toDoItem)` within a write block. See the example in the [Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#many-to-one)'

Comment: Thank you, already fixed it by obtaining value of selectedCategory from pickerview value.